# c++ what happens if callee deletes caller?

Tags: c++

is the behaviour in a c++ app defined if a callee function deletes the object in which the caller (member) function is defined? will the rest of the caller function body still be executed? will it run correctly if it doesn't access any member variables?

I just ask because I found this case  in my application (the result of some juggling with member function pointers) and I was surprised why it doesn't make my app crash.

Comment: With the help of trunk, you can climb on to a tree-branch. What happens if you try to cut the trunk after climbing to the branch :(

Comment: @Mahesh You float in midair till you're ready to jump down (safely), you just can't take any new leaves with you ;)

Comment: @Andrew - Well, that is what undefined behavior is. We aren't sure, whether we can land safely or not ?

Comment: @Mahesh: What about writing code, compiled with various compilers and test it on various platforms? It's just no point guessing here. No philosophy needed.

Comment: The correct answer is already below, but it may be helpful to think of it this way: code is not data.  Code does not get deleted when the data it was using does, but depending on how it uses the data that was deleted problems could arise.

Comment: @Dan: Code is data (on Von Neumann architecture systems), but code is not part of the object instance where member data is stored.

Comment: @Viet: We actually need some philosophy with C++ and undefined behavior. If it really **is** undefined, the tests will be invalid and you just can't trust the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is the expected behavior. As long as the code does not access any non-static member objects or functions, there is no reason why it can't keep running.

Comment: Thats the problem. If a member function does not know it (the object) has been deleted then how can it know not to touch any of its own non-static members. This makes the code very brittle and likely to be unmaintainable in the long run (any maintenance that changes the behavior even slightly is going to cause all sorts of problems).

Comment: @Martin: I'm not saying it's a good practice. Just that it's not undefined behavior.

Comment: @Martin: classic example is probably self-refcounting objects. Not that I'm saying *that's* good practice either, but it's not particularly brittle regarding object existence. Your `deref` or `close` non-static member function wants to (conditionally) delete the object as the last thing before returning, it knows it's never going to explicitly use `this` or access data members afterwards. Anything calling `deref` would behave likewise. And of course after 20 minutes you'd give up the whole scheme and use `shared_ptr`, but because the code *doesn't work*, not because it's unmaintainable ;-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop: The other classic example I have seen is the close button on the window. Click the close button it activates the close handler which eventually deletes the windows object. Unfortunately windowing systems are exceedingly complex and usually there are lots of registered event handlers that kick off after the fact. Thus in this situation it is usually best **NOT** to do self delete but register yourself for deletion with a manager by posting another event. Then once all processing has been done on this event the manager will kick in and delete the object.

Answer (score 1):

A notable exception to "yes the rest of the caller will run" is Win32's [`FreeLibraryAndExitThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683153.aspx), which REALLY deletes the caller, stack space, code, and all.

Answer (score -3):

The code is still on the stack even though the destructor was called.  You can't depend on the fact that any free'd memory won't be overwritten in the meanwhile, though.  If it isn't overwritten, however, and the destructor doesn't otherwise overwrite anything critical, things would go along smoothly.